# Flutter firebase_ml_vision build failed with exception

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-machine-learning

Android build keeps crashing with firebase_ml_vision being the dependency that causes it.

Below is the output from the debug console when running a build for android.

```
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.
  2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.
  
  Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-co
  mmon@[19.0.2], but play-services-vision-common version was 19.1.0.
  
  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the artifact with the issue.
 -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@{strictly 24.1.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_ml_vision' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@20.0.
  0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@{strictly 19.1.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-bom@{strictly 25.12.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-bom@25.12.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label@{strictly 18.0.4}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@{strictly 20.0.0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your `android/app/build.gradle` file.

At the bottom, you should have a `dependencies object`. Remove the concrete version from firebase-bom below.

Before:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    ...
}
```

After:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom')
    ...
}
```