# Firebase_auth depends on firebase_core error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
smooth_star_rating: ^1.0.4
geopoint: ^0.7.1
geoflutterfire: ^2.2.1
google_maps: ^4.0.0
firebase_core: ^0.7.0

Because firebase_auth 0.18.4+1 depends on firebase_core ^0.5.3 and no versions of firebase_auth match >0.18.4+1 <0.19.0, firebase_auth ^0.18.4+1 requires firebase_core ^0.5.3.
So, because app_name depends on both firebase_auth ^0.18.4+1 and firebase_core ^0.7.0, version solving failed.

pub get failed (1; So, because app_name depends on both firebase_auth ^0.18.4+1 and firebase_core ^0.7.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

Comment: This question may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293457/flutter-firebase-ml-vision-build-failed-with-exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just import these packages with these **exact versions** like that

```
firebase_auth:^0.18.4+1


firebase_core ^0.5.3
```

Comment: @mustafazaki this answer or changing the `firebase_core: ^0.7.0` to `firebase_core ^0.5.3` will fix the issue. I upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use latest version of **firebase_auth** and try again.

set **firebase_auth:^0.18.4+1**

To

**firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1**