# Package version incompatibilities

Tags: flutter, dart

Because firebase_ui_auth >=1.0.3 depends on firebase_core ^2.1.1 and cloud_firestore >=3.1.2 <4.0.1 depends on firebase_core ^1.10.2, firebase_ui_auth >=1.0.3 is incompatible with cloud_firestore >=3.1.2 <4.0.1.
So, because "my_project" depends on both cloud_firestore ^3.4.2 and firebase_ui_auth ^1.0.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because "my_project" depends on both cloud_firestore ^3.4.2 and firebase_ui_auth ^1.0.3, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Try upgrading all the packages

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293457/flutter-firebase-ml-vision-build-failed-with-exception

Comment: @DulajAriyaratne, Does not help :(

Comment: @Th3Ph4nt0m, Does not help :(

Comment: Can you post your `pubspec.yaml` file here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```yaml
  firebase_ui_auth: ^1.0.0-dev.0 # or ^1.0.3
  firebase_core: ^1.24.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.4.9
```

Comment: glad to help,  also you can remove the version or replace with `any` and run flutter get and then check version number on `pubspec.lock`

Comment: @Alexandr Just to explain what exactly the problem was: the versions of the individual packages were not compatible with each other. What you have done now is to adjust the versions so that everything works together again.